# How to add a custom page size Width and Height on GemBox.Spreadsheet.ExcelWorksheet

Tags: .net, gembox-spreadsheet

I am trying to print a pdf document based on a ExcelFile. I want to print a doc that's 100x34, so quite small. The [default page sizes](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/docs/GemBox.Spreadsheet.PaperType.html) doesn't support this size, but I checked that they have a Custom option. I'm just not able to make it work.

This is the code:

```
 var workbook = ExcelFile.Load(stream);
 ExcelWorksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];
 worksheet.PrintOptions.PaperType = PaperType.Custom;

 using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
 {
     workbook.Save(memoryStream, saveOptions);
     return (memoryStream.ToArray());
 }
```

I saw some examples on their documentation but it doesn't work. This one would be perfect, but it doesn't work: https://forum.gemboxsoftware.com/t/set-printoptions-papertype-to-a0-or-a1/264/2

Does anyone knows how to set the custom width and height of the document?

Comment: To what format are you saving the `ExcelFile`, in other words, what is the type of the `saveOptions`? If you're saving to XLSX, note that those custom sizes are specific to printers. You may notice this by creating the desired XLSX file "manually" (using Microsoft Excel). Can you send me that desired XLSX file that you create? I can investigate it and let you know how to create the same with GemBox.Spreadsheet.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Let me see if I understood the question. The paper size A6 stands for or is like 100x150 inches. What I need is to generate the pdf in 100x34 inches.

Comment: Ok so you are saving the `ExcelFile` to PDF, is that correct? In that case, the `System.Printing.PageMediaSize` approach should work. You have tried that code from the forum post and it didn't work for you, is that correct? In that case, can you create a small Visual Studio project that reproduces your issue so that I can investigate it? I tried that code from the forum post and it worked for me.